# Where does Google Chrome store its history?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to view my history from before three months ago. Search only goes back three. Where does Chrome store the older history? I'm reading that it used to, but now it doesn't. This is rather confusing.

Comment: If search only goes back three you have only three months of data saved.

Answer (score -1):

Your computer stores history as a cache; however, if you go to the upper right hand corner of google, you will see all of the history. If you deleted it, you are out of luck.

Comment: What do you mean "upper-right hand corner"?

Comment: there will be 3 horizontal lines next to the address bar

Comment: I'm talking about the file for it.

Comment: google chrome does not store history in a windows directory like IE does. Google creates a specific folder in AppData that stores the history provider, thats a cache and encrypted. You are looking at it. It is stored in the actual application of chrome. you can try %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low or internet properties; but that is relative to IE